# Active MQ Topic Consumer fails to consume some messages

Tags: java, android, activemq-classic, stomp

I have a producer/consumer client whose topic is on Active MQ using Stomp protocol.
I use Gozirra.

Problem is not all the messages produced at the other end of conversation 
arrive at consumer client as coded below.
Some messages successfully arrives but the others fails to come in.

I heard loss of messages is due to asynchronous nature of messaging implemented
based on consumer/producer model.

Some say using receipt mechanism may help.

What do you think is the problem?

=========================================================================

## code below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import com.lnisoft.ontocept.StringEscapeUtils;
import net.ser1.stomp.Client;
import net.ser1.stomp.Listener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


// * Active MQ Stomp client using Gozirra

public class Communicator implements Listener 
{
private static Communicator instance;
private Client stomp_client = null;
private ConnectToOntoceptAsync connector = null;

private String emailAsUserIdentifier = "";
private String topicName = null;
private String messageToSend = "NO_MESSAGE";

private boolean isLoggedIn = false;
private StreamConverter converter = null;
private String errorMessage = "";
private boolean hasError = false;
public HashMap<String, MessageStack> perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl = new HashMap<String, MessageStack>();

public Communicator()
{
     converter = new StreamConverter();
}

public static Communicator getInstance()
{
     if ( instance == null )
     {
          instance = new Communicator();
     }

     return instance;
}

@Override 
public void message( Map headers, String body ) 
{ 
      String ascii_to_unicode = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava( body ); 

      if ( ((String)headers.get("sender")).contains("ontocept") )
      {
          storeMessageFromOntocept( ascii_to_unicode );
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("my message : "+ ascii_to_unicode);               
          System.out.println("\n"); 
      }
} 

public boolean getIsLoggedIn()
{
     return this.isLoggedIn;
}

public void initializeCommunicator( String _emailAsUserIdentifier ) throws LoginException, IOException
{       
    this.emailAsUserIdentifier = _emailAsUserIdentifier;

    topicName = "/topic/"+ this.emailAsUserIdentifier;

    connector = new ConnectToOntoceptAsync();
    connector.execute();
}

public boolean isIntialized() 
{
     if ( isLoggedIn == false )
     {
           return false;
     }
     else
     {
          return true;
     }
}

protected class ConnectToOntoceptAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{       
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( String... params )  
    {
        try 
        { 
             stomp_client = new Client( "***.***.**.***", 61613, emailAsUserIdentifier,  "1234" );  
             stomp_client.subscribe( topicName, Communicator.this  );
             isLoggedIn = true; 

        } 
        catch (LoginException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

         return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String text) 
    {
          // TODO 
    }
}

public boolean hasError()
{
     return this.hasError;
}

public String getError()
{
     return this.errorMessage;
}

public void disconnect()
{
    stomp_client.unsubscribe( this.topicName );
    stomp_client.disconnect();
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
}

public void sendMessageToOntocept( String _messageText )
{
     this.messageToSend = _messageText;

     new SendAsyncMessageToOntocept().execute();
}

private class SendAsyncMessageToOntocept extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( String... params )  
    { 
        String unicode_formatted_message = converter.convertToUnicodeText( messageToSend  ); 

        Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<String,String>();

        // * http://www.germane-software.com/software/Java/Gozirra/
        header.put( "type", "text/plain" );  
        header.put( "sender", "user" );

        stomp_client.send( topicName, unicode_formatted_message, header );

        try 
        { 
            Thread.sleep(2000); 
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        Thread.yield(); 

        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String text) 
    { }
}

public boolean hasNewMessage( String _messageRecipientIdentifier )
{ 
      if ( _messageRecipientIdentifier.contains("quiz_activity") )
      {
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity") == null )
            {
                   return false;
            }
            else
            {
                 return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity").existNewMessage();
            }
      }
      else if ( _messageRecipientIdentifier.contains("vms_activity") )   // VisualizeMemorySpace 액티비티 약자
      {
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity") == null )
            {
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                   return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity").existNewMessage();
            }
      }
      else  // _messageRecipientIdentifier = Ontocept_Activity
      { 
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity") == null )
            {
                   return false;
            }
            else
            {
                   return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity").existNewMessage();
            }
      }
}

public Message getNewMessage( String _messageRecipientIdentifier )
{
      if ( _messageRecipientIdentifier.contains("quiz_activity") )
      {
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity") == null )
            {
                  return null;
            }
            else
            {
                 return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity").getNewMessage();
            }
      }
      else if ( _messageRecipientIdentifier.contains("vms_activity") ) 
      {
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity") == null )
            {
                  return null;
            }
            else
            {
                   return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity").getNewMessage();
            }
      }
      else  // _messageRecipientIdentifier = Ontocept_Activity
      { 
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity") == null )
            {
                   return null;
            }
            else
            {
                   return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity").getNewMessage();
            }
      }
}

public String convertToUnicodeText( String str )
{
     StringBuffer ostr = new StringBuffer();

     for ( int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) 
     {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);

            if ((ch >= 0x0020) && (ch <= 0x007e))   // Does the char need to be converted to unicode? 
            {
                    ostr.append(ch);                    // No.
            } 
            else                                    // Yes.
            {
                    ostr.append("\\u") ;                // standard unicode format.
                    String hex = Integer.toHexString(str.charAt(i) & 0xFFFF);   // Get hex value of the char. 
                    for(int j=0; j<4-hex.length(); j++) // Prepend zeros because unicode requires 4 digits
                        ostr.append("0");
                    ostr.append(hex.toLowerCase());     // standard unicode format.
                    //ostr.append(hex.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
            }
        }

      return (new String(ostr));        //Return the stringbuffer cast as a string.
}

private void storeMessageFromOntocept( String messageObjectString ) 
{ 
      Message messageObject =   MessageObjectGenerator.getInstance().parseMessageStringIntoMessageObject( messageObjectString );

      if ( messageObject.getRecipient().contains("ontocept_activity") )
      {
            if ( this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity") == null )
            {
                  MessageStack ms = new MessageStack();

                  ms.addMessage( messageObject );

                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.put( "ontocept_activity", ms );
            }
            else
            {
                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity").addMessage( messageObject );
            }
      }
      else if ( messageObject.getRecipient().contains("vms_activity") )   
      {
            if ( this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity") == null )
            {
                  MessageStack ms = new MessageStack();

                  ms.addMessage( messageObject );

                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.put( "vms_activity", ms );
            }
            else
            {
                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity").addMessage( messageObject );
            }
      }
      else 
      { 
            if ( this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity") == null )
            {
                  MessageStack ms = new MessageStack();

                  ms.addMessage( messageObject );

                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.put( "ontocept_activity", ms );
            }
            else
            {
                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity").addMessage( messageObject );
            }
      }
}

public HashMap<String, MessageStack> getMessageStack()
{
     return this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an Android app. So it is required that the app is always active, or else the communication to the server will be interrupted, causing message loss.

Are you sure that Listener will be called from within the background thread? To connect to the server, your AsyncTask ConnectToOntoceptAsync runs and immediately returns. On Android, all network communication must happen on a separate thread. To me this looks suspicious.

I would do all communication on the background thread, so the Stomp client is a private field of the AsyncTask. Also instead of using the Listener interface I prefer use the blocking receive methods, which give more detailed control.

Comment: Oh you're quite right. As you said, I've added Receipt process on the other to make sure that the message sent therein safely arrived at client activity. Since the client is mobile device, I doubt that Subscriber client may lose connection anytime. So I am considering MQTT. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I leave a current version of my code which does not lose a message from the other end point.

I've divided Client to one as Subscriber which is instantiated only once during session and

the other as Message Producer which is instantiated every time I need to send a message

and have it disconnected. I don't know if this is a right way to do.

But until now, all the messages ( chatting messages ) are safely received.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import com.lnisoft.ontocept.StringEscapeUtils;

import net.ser1.stomp.Client;
import net.ser1.stomp.Listener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

// * Active MQ Stomp using Gozirra
public class Communicator 
{
private static Communicator instance;
private Client subscriber = null;
private Client stomp_client = null;
private ConnectToOntoceptAsync connector = null;
private String emailAsUserIdentifier = "";
    private String topicName = null;


private String messageToSend = "NO_MESSAGE";


private boolean isLoggedIn = false;


private StreamConverter converter = null;


private String errorMessage = "";
private boolean hasError = false;


public HashMap<String, MessageStack> perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl = new HashMap<String, MessageStack>();


public Communicator()
{
     converter = new StreamConverter();
}

public static Communicator getInstance()
{
     if ( instance == null )
     {
          instance = new Communicator();
     }

     return instance;
}


public boolean getIsLoggedIn()
{
     return this.isLoggedIn;
}

public void initializeCommunicator( String _emailAsUserIdentifier ) throws LoginException, IOException
{       
    this.emailAsUserIdentifier = _emailAsUserIdentifier;


    topicName = "/topic/"+ this.emailAsUserIdentifier;

    connector = new ConnectToOntoceptAsync();
    connector.execute();
}

public boolean isIntialized() 
{
     if ( isLoggedIn == false )
     {
           return false;
     }
     else
     {
          return true;
     }
}

protected class ConnectToOntoceptAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{       
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( String... params )  
    {
        try 
        { 
             subscriber = new Client( "***.***.**.***", 61613, emailAsUserIdentifier,  "1234" ); 

             subscriber.subscribe( topicName, new Listener() 
             {
                    public void message( Map header, String body ) 
                    { 
                          String ascii_to_unicode = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava( body ); 

                          if ( ((String)header.get("sender")).contains("ontocept") )
                          {
                              storeMessageFromOntocept( ascii_to_unicode );
                          }
                    }
                  } );

                  isLoggedIn = true;   
        } 
        catch (LoginException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

         return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String text) 
    {
          // TODO 
    }
}

public boolean hasError()
{
     return this.hasError;
}

public String getError()
{
     return this.errorMessage;
}

public void disconnect()
{
    subscriber.unsubscribe( this.topicName );
    subscriber.disconnect();

    this.isLoggedIn = false;
}

public void sendMessageToOntocept( String _messageText )
{
     this.messageToSend = _messageText;

     new SendAsyncMessageToOntocept().execute();
}

private class SendAsyncMessageToOntocept extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( String... params )  
    { 
        synchronized ( this )
        {
            try 
            { 
                if ( stomp_client != null )
                {
                    if ( stomp_client.isConnected() == true )
                    {
                        stomp_client.disconnect();
                    }
                }

                stomp_client = new Client( "***.***.**.***", 61613, emailAsUserIdentifier,  "1234" );   

                String unicode_formatted_message = converter.convertToUnicodeText( messageToSend  );  

                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<String,String>();

                // * http://www.germane-software.com/software/Java/Gozirra/
                header.put( "type", "text/plain" );  
                header.put( "sender", "user" );

                try 
                { 
                    Thread.sleep(2000); 
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 

                stomp_client.send( topicName, unicode_formatted_message, header );

                try 
                { 
                    Thread.sleep(2000); 
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 

                stomp_client.disconnect();

                Thread.yield(); 
            } 
            catch (LoginException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        }




        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String text) 
    { }
}


public boolean hasNewMessage( String _messageRecipientIdentifier )
{ 
      if ( _messageRecipientIdentifier.contains("quiz_activity") )
      {
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity") == null )
            {
                   return false;
            }
            else
            {
                 return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity").existNewMessage();
            }
      }
      else if ( _messageRecipientIdentifier.contains("vms_activity") )   
      {
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity") == null )
            {
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                   return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity").existNewMessage();
            }
      }
      else  // _messageRecipientIdentifier = Ontocept_Activity
      { 
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity") == null )
            {
                   return false;
            }
            else
            {
                   return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity").existNewMessage();
            }
      }
}

public Message getNewMessage( String _messageRecipientIdentifier )
{
      if ( _messageRecipientIdentifier.contains("quiz_activity") )
      {
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity") == null )
            {
                  return null;
            }
            else
            {
                 return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity").getNewMessage();
            }
      }
      else if ( _messageRecipientIdentifier.contains("vms_activity") )  
      {
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity") == null )
            {
                  return null;
            }
            else
            {
                   return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity").getNewMessage();
            }
      }
      else  // _messageRecipientIdentifier = Ontocept_Activity
      { 
            if ( perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity") == null )
            {
                   return null;
            }
            else
            {
                   return perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity").getNewMessage();
            }
      }
}

public String convertToUnicodeText( String str )
{
     StringBuffer ostr = new StringBuffer();

     for ( int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) 
     {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);

            if ((ch >= 0x0020) && (ch <= 0x007e))   // Does the char need to be converted to unicode? 
            {
                    ostr.append(ch);                    // No.
            } 
            else                                    // Yes.
            {
                    ostr.append("\\u") ;                // standard unicode format.
                    String hex = Integer.toHexString(str.charAt(i) & 0xFFFF);   // Get hex value of the char. 
                    for(int j=0; j<4-hex.length(); j++) // Prepend zeros because unicode requires 4 digits
                        ostr.append("0");
                    ostr.append(hex.toLowerCase());     // standard unicode format.
                    //ostr.append(hex.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
            }
        }

      return (new String(ostr));        //Return the stringbuffer cast as a string.
}


private void storeMessageFromOntocept( String messageObjectString ) 
{ 
      Message messageObject = MessageObjectGenerator.getInstance().parseMessageStringIntoMessageObject( messageObjectString );

      if ( messageObject.getRecipient().contains("quiz_activity") )
      {
            if ( this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity") == null )
            {
                  MessageStack ms = new MessageStack();

                  ms.addMessage( messageObject );

                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.put( "quiz_activity", ms );
            }
            else
            {
                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("quiz_activity").addMessage( messageObject );
            }
      }
      else if ( messageObject.getRecipient().contains("vms_activity") )   
      {
            if ( this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity") == null )
            {
                  MessageStack ms = new MessageStack();

                  ms.addMessage( messageObject );

                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.put( "vms_activity", ms );
            }
            else
            {
                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("vms_activity").addMessage( messageObject );
            }
      }
      else  
      {               
            if ( this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity") == null )
            {
                  MessageStack ms = new MessageStack();

                  ms.addMessage( messageObject );

                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.put( "ontocept_activity", ms );
            }
            else
            {
                  this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl.get("ontocept_activity").addMessage( messageObject );
            }
      }
}

public HashMap<String, MessageStack> getMessageStack()
{
     return this.perCommunicatorUserMessageStackTbl;
}
```

}